# Creating RDS Datasource fails with "AmazonRDSException: The security token included in the request is invalid"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I am unable to start an application with

```
@EnableRdsInstance(databaseName = "test",
        dbInstanceIdentifier = "test",
        password = "password",
        username = "username",
        readReplicaSupport = true
)
```

The exception I get is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'test': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.rds.model.AmazonRDSException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID: 925519ec-582e-11e7-8ca6-8159eafdc3e8)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ...
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.rds.model.AmazonRDSException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID: 925519ec-582e-11e7-8ca6-8159eafdc3e8)
    at ...
```

Tried all configurations that are suggested in [Spring Cloud AWS Docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/1.2.1.RELEASE/) including ENV variable, System.setProperties(), and in application.yml as below

```
cloud:
  aws:
    credentials:
      accessKey: XXXXXXX
      secretKey: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    region:
      static: us-east-2
```

also tried even hardcoding in in aws-beans

```
<beans ...>

    <aws-context:context-credentials>
        <aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="XXXXXXXXXX" secret-key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    </aws-context:context-credentials>

    <aws-context:context-resource-loader/>

    <aws-context:context-region region="us-east-2" />

</beans>
```

and nothing works, help is appreciated....

Comment: Do you remember the solution you came up with? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons to get this exception:

- Make sure public access is enabled for RDS Instance and allow incoming traffic for your machine in Security Group.
- Make sure internet gateway is attached with VPC and very importantly you have to use public subnet rather than private subnet.

Comment: I was able to access thr db from workbench in my machine, the only problem is with spring-cloud-aws unable to send accesskey/secretkey due to some possible misconfiguration.

Comment: No, the problem as I said is with the framework in picking up access and secret keys, and I'm not sure if how to proceed next

Comment: Can you paste pom.xml file? So I can able to figure out the problem.